# Getting references of all values from a map to a vector in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, reference

I have a map, say `map<string, TContext> MyMap;`
`Tcontext` contains a member `errorResult`.
I want to assign references of all values' `TContext`'s errorResult from `MyMap` to a `vector`. It will be even better If it could be done without a for loop.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear to me, but it sounds like it may be solved by [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: You need a loop.  Whether you hide that loop in a function like `std::tranform`, or you just write a ranged based for loop, you still need loop.

Comment: Why without a loop, if you mean without loop syntax ok but any approach will require looping unless you have the keys duplicated in another container.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in a vector must be [assignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable). C++ references are not assignables (talking about the reference themselves here, not their content. They're like a `T * const` pointer if you will).
So either make a vector of `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, or just pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this

```
std::vector<const int*> ordinals;
std::transform(MyMap.cbegin(), MyMap.cend(), std::back_inserter(ordinals),
               [](const std::pair<string, TContext>& c) -> const int* { return &(c.second.errorResult); });
```

If by references you literally mean references, you can use std:: reference_wrapper, as suggested by m88